# I think we need a definite article here, but the book says no!

Tags: definite-article

According to [Common Mistakes at IELTS Intermediate by Pauline Cullen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521692466) Page 5 question 3, The following sentence is correct:

> My father has fished in rivers all over Australia.

And this one is incorrect:

> My father has fished in **the** rivers all over Australia.

Why is that? I guess we have to use "**the**" before rivers, because it is clear that we are talking about particular rivers that are located in Australia.

Comment: Did you copy that correctly? Does it actually say "all over the Australia" is correct?

Comment: For a general notion, you don't need the.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for your consideration. I checked it, it was "all over Australia". I edited the question. But my question is about the rivers ,  I mean "the" before rivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***In the rivers*** would imply *in **all** the rivers of Australia*. This cannot be possibly true, though, ok, maybe some Guiness Book fisherman may have done it. It is more accurate to say ***in rivers***:

> ***in (some) rivers all over Australia***.

This post from ELU, *[Definite article before “Houses”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/518475/definite-article-before-houses)*, deals with a similar issue.

Comment: I wouldn't say it isn't possible, but based on the original statement, probably not the intent.

Answer (score 1):

The question states, "it is clear that we are talking about particular rivers in Australia."

This is not correct.  This appears to be a misreading of the sentence, which analyses it like this, "my father has fished in **the rivers that are all over** Australia."

The sentence should rather be understood like this, "My father has fished in rivers - where has he fished in rivers - he has fished in rivers [while he has been] all over Australia."

Consider this possible extension of the original sentence: "My father has fished in rivers all over Australia, but he has only done deep sea fishing near Brisbane."

Or, even closer to the original, "My father has gone fly fishing all over Australia."